# Hugo theme similar to bookdown.org?

Tags: hugo, bookdown, blogdown

I am building a website using Hugo and wondering if there is any theme link this one: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/

Answer (score 0):

I've looked for the same thing.  The closest I've found thus far is the [DocDock theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/docdock/).   It's similar insofar as it is a responsive theme with a sidebar capable of navigating content several levels deep, although the default theme color scheme is probably somewhat more contrast-y than some might prefer.  I've [extended it a bit](https://github.com/laakmann/hugo-theme-docdock-plus) to integrate some blogging features for a site I'm planning on launching soon.

I might create a gitbook-style or bookdown-style hugo theme (it's really pretty simple) and then enhance it a bit so that "book" features can be integrated seamlessly into something resembling more of a conventional blog.